# insert image into flexbox view

Tags: react-native

am using react native and i create view styles with cards, 
and what i want to do is just inserting images inside the cards.

here is my codes:

```
<View style={styles.card}>
        <Image style={styles.img} source={require('./shjpolice.jpg')} />
</View>
<View style={styles.card} />
<View style={styles.card} />
<View style={styles.card} />



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     feed: {
         flex: 1,
         flexDirection: 'row',
         flexWrap: 'wrap',
         padding: 16,
         justifyContent: 'space-between'  
     },
     card: {
         backgroundColor: 'grey',
         width: '48%',
         aspectRatio: 1,
         marginBottom: 16
     },
     img: {
         flex : 2 ,
         resizeMode : 'stretch',
         resizeMode:'contain'
     }
});
```

and the output is below image

[image: out put in emulator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you missed to give it a width and height.
I have faced this issue few times, but should fix with a width and height.
Try

```
img: {
    flex : 1 ,
    resizeMode : 'stretch',
    resizeMode:'contain',
    width:'100%',
    height: '100%'

}
```

Comment: resizeMode is a prop related to Image.